# How can I sign my application a good way?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-developers-console

I have a quite normal app for Android which requires no permission at all. I wanted to upload the APK to the Google Play Developer Console.

In Android Studio, I pressed Build --> Generate Signed APK... --> I filled in the correct passwords --> Next --> Build Type debug --> Signature Versions only V2 (Full APK Signature) --> Finish.

My loggs tell me: APK's generated succesfully.

I go to the Google Play Developer Console --> Release management --> App-releases --> Edit bèta release --> Upload APK.

When I upload the APK that's just created I get the following error from Google:

> Upload failed. You have uploaded an unsigned APK. You must create a
>   signed APK.

This is very irritating, because it happens always when I try to upload an APK, which is signed according to me. I tried several ways. What have I done wrong?

Comment: "Build Type debug" I think this is your problem, this should be "Build Type Release".  [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) see figure 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose Build type Release and check both signature versions V1 and V2.

[image]

[Signature Versions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2)

> Android 7.0 introduces APK Signature Scheme v2, a new app-signing
>   scheme that offers faster app install times and more protection
>   against unauthorized alterations to APK files. By default, Android
>   Studio 2.2 and the Android Plugin for Gradle 2.2 sign your app using
>   both APK Signature Scheme v2 and the traditional signing scheme, which
>   uses JAR signing.

Signature V2 is optional, but signature V1 is mandatory for distribution on Google Play.

Comment: "and check both signature versions V1 and V2" what does this mean?

Comment: @weston There are two signature version checkboxes. Both should be checked. I will upload image in a minute.

Comment: Oh the checkboxes - I get you